# Reading characters and checking if they're a number

Tags: java, file, integer, character, letter

I am trying to get a method that checks if character after the symbol & is a number or a letter; if a number, it is translated into binary; and if it is a letter, it is set to 16 and is incremented by 1 if a different word is being used. The trouble is, this doesn't work for me, for some reason. Any suggestions?

```
try {
       ReadFile files = new ReadFile(file.getPath());
       String[] anyLines = files.OpenFile();

       int i;

       for (i=0; i<anyLines.length; i++) {
           String input = anyLines[i];
           String[] lines = input.split("\n");

           int wordValue = 16;

           Map<String, Integer> wordValueMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

           for (String line : lines) {
               // if line doesn't begin with &, then ignore it
               if (!line.startsWith("&")) {
                   continue;
               }

               // remove &
               line = line.substring(1);

               Integer binaryValue = null;

               if (line.matches("\\d+")) {
                   binaryValue = Integer.toBinaryString(131072 +
                              Integer.parseInt(anyLines[i])).substring(2,18);
               }
               else if (line.matches("\\w+")) {
                   binaryValue = wordValueMap.get(line);

                   if (binaryValue == null) {
                       binaryValue = wordValue;
                       wordValueMap.put(line, binaryValue);
                       wordValue++;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
```

INPUT:

```
&4
...
&hello
...
&ok
```

OUTPUT:

```
(5 translated into binary) : 0000000000000100
...
(16 translated into binary)
...
(17 translated into binary, or 16+1)
```

---

Here's the output of your method:

```
101
1001100
1001100
1001100
1001100
1001100
1001100
1001100
&5
1110110000010000 
&hello
1110001100001000 
&goodbye
1110101010001000 
(NEXT)
&goodbye
1111000010001000 
&hello
1110001110001000 
&BILL
1110001100000110 
&NEXT
1110101010000111 
(BILL)
&BILL
1110101010000111
```

And here's the original text that i'm reading and looping through (anyLines[i] without any modifications):

```
&5
var1 
&hello
var2 
&goodbye
var2 
(NEXT)
&goodbye
var3 
&hello
var4 
&BILL
var5 
&NEXT
var6 
(BILL)
&BILL
var5
```

var is just a variable that has a value. I already took care of those.

---

Here's my attempt:

```
String input = "This is a test line\n"
           + "&hello\n"
           + "&4\n"
           + "&32";

String[] lines = input.split("\n");
int wordValue = 26;

Map<String, Integer> wordValueMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String currentLine : lines)
{
if (!currentLine.startsWith("&"))
{
    continue;
}

currentLine = currentLine.substring(1);
Integer value;

if (currentLine.matches("\\d+"))
{
    value = Integer.parseInt(currentLine);
}
else if (currentLine.matches("\\w+"))
{
    value = wordValueMap.get(currentLine);

    if(value == null)
    {
        int binaryValue = wordValue++;
        wordValueMap.replace(currentLine, binaryValue);
        /*
         * This is just there to ensure that the print statement below doesn't have a 
         * null value.
         */
        value = binaryValue;
    }
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
    break;
}

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
}
```

Comment: Can you describe in what manner it "doesn't work"?

Comment: It just leaves the string as it is found, with the "&" symbol, even though i clearly said i didn't want it

Comment: Can you simplify your code and narrow down where the problem is? Answering questions is fun, but there's a lot there. Adding some example input and output would also help.

Comment: When you are taking the substring, did you mean to take the substring of the binary string, or of anylines[i]?

Comment: Also what is the purpose of the 131072 in the toBinaryString method?

Comment: @Varun, it a round about way of zero padding the binary number. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems with your code.
To begin with, you'll have to parse the value you get after the toBinaryString() call.

```
binaryValue = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(131072 +
                          Integer.parseInt(anyLines[i])).substring(2,18));
```

The usage of anyLines[i] as an argument to the parseInt() function in that code is also incorrect. From what I see of your code, anyLines[i] is a string with newLines and other things in it, which obviously cannot be parsed into an integer.

The code below seems to work. I've changed the storage of the HashMap so that it stores regular integers, instead of attempting to store a binary representation as an integer value.

```
String input = "This is a test line\n"
               + "&hello\n"
               + "&4\n"
               + "&32";

String[] lines = input.split("\n");
int wordValue = 26;

Map<String, Integer> wordValueMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String currentLine : lines)
{
    if (!currentLine.startsWith("&"))
    {
        continue;
    }

    currentLine = currentLine.substring(1);
    Integer value;

    if (currentLine.matches("\\d+"))
    {
        value = Integer.parseInt(currentLine);
    }
    else if (currentLine.matches("\\w+"))
    {
        value = wordValueMap.get(currentLine);

        if(value == null)
        {
            int binaryValue = wordValue++;
            wordValueMap.put(currentLine, binaryValue);
            /*
             * This is just there to ensure that the print statement below doesn't have a 
             * null value.
             */
            value = binaryValue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        break;
    }

    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
}
```

As a side note, I hope you know that this will fail in the event of a number followed by a words, like sentences. But if your input will never have any of that, it's a non-issue.

Comment: +1 I think this is the main problem. After going to all the work of creating `line` from `anyLines[i]`, this code simply goes back to the original line.

Comment: I spent a lot of time simply trying to figure out what this code did.

Comment: So what do you suggest I should do?

Comment: I'd recommend you store the values as Integers, rather than attempting to store them as binaryStrings. Then when you need to convert them to binary string for some reason or the other, use the toBinaryString() method.

Comment: The only problem I have is that it reads the file and doesn't increment the word value - if one line reads @hello and another line reads @goodbye , both words have same value - 16, though @hello should have a value of 16, and @goodbye - 17 because value 16 is already exclusively reserved for @hello.

Comment: @rudna1010 - that isn't true. I changed the input to have the &hello have one line, and &goodbye on the next line and it correctly incremented the values. I then also added &nope as the last line to see if something went wrong when words were separated by numbers, and that worked fine as well.

Comment: @Varun Madiath, well, maybe it's because of my input - I input a string array to read any file instead of just a hard-coded string. As you can see above, the string input is anyLines[i], not a hard-coded string. That might be the problem.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Can you give me an example of exactly what you're setting input to be. Just print out anylines[i] and paste it below.

Comment: The point for me is to actually replace the characters with the binary numbers (like &5 should be physically replaced with 101).

What do you mean padding? I'm not using leading zeros in my program.

Comment: Where should it be replaced? and what I meant by the padding was the addition of 131072 in the code you provided or `1110110000010000` in your second output above

Comment: I'm not adding the 131072 into the code and it still outputs the same. I want to physically replace %5 with 0000000000000101 (so that it would say:

`0000000000000101`(next line)

`1110110000010000`(next line)

`0000000000010000`(next line)

`1110001100001000`(next line)

and so on...

Comment: Well, once you have the value, why don't you just create a new string with the value, and use that?

Comment: what do you mean by that? How would I do that?

Comment: Either use the replace function in the String class, or just construct a new string with the desired value.

Comment: The issue with what you have is that you're supposed to use the replace method on a string, not on a hashmap. The hashmaps replace function does something completely different. I'll try modifying my code to do what you want a little later.

Comment: @Varun Madiath: I used replace method, but it still doesn't work (see the code above). Can you point me in the right direction?