# Why is this code looping 16 times?

Tags: java, file, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacing symbol with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181954/replacing-symbol-with-a-number)

Here's the code:

Read File method:

```
package textfiles;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReadFile {

private String path;

// create a method which takes in the classpath of the file
public ReadFile(String filePath) {
path = filePath;

}

public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {
FileReader reader = new FileReader(path);
BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

List<String> textData = new LinkedList<String>();
String line;

while ((line = textReader.readLine()) != null) {
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("//.*$", Pattern.DOTALL);
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
   line = matcher.replaceFirst("");
   if (line.trim().length()==0) continue;
   if (!line.startsWith("//")) { textData.add(line); }
   else if (!line.startsWith("(")) { textData.add(line); }





}

 // close the line-by-line reader and return the data
 textReader.close();
 return textData.toArray(new String[textData.size()]);
}
}
```

AND MY main method:

```
try {
    ReadFile files = new ReadFile(file.getPath());
    String[] anyLines = files.OpenFile();

    int i;



     //  test if the program actually read the file
     for (i=0; i<anyLines.length; i++) {
         int wordValue = 16;

         // to keep track words that are already used
         Map<String, Integer> wordValueMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

         for (String line : anyLines) {

             // if line doesn't begin with &, then ignore it
             if (!line.startsWith("@")) {
                 continue;
             }

             // remove &
             line = line.substring(1);

             Integer binaryValue = null;

             if (line.matches("\\d+")) {
                 binaryValue = Integer.parseInt(line);
             }
             else if (line.matches("\\w+")) {
                 binaryValue = wordValueMap.get(line);

                // if the map doesn't contain the word value, then assign and store it

                 if (binaryValue == null) {
                     binaryValue = wordValue;
                      wordValueMap.put(line, binaryValue);
                     wordValue++;
                 }
           }

       // I'm using Commons Lang's StringUtils.leftPad(..) to create the zero padded string
       System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(binaryValue));


    }
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting. Please see the edit I made to your other related thread, [replacing-symbol-with-a-number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181954/replacing-symbol-with-a-number), and address the issues they raise.

Comment: @rudna1010 can you post all your code?

Comment: @trutheality, anyLines is an array with the length of the file (19 lines in this case)

Comment: @GeorgeBecj: I think that's the only code that we're concerned with (I posted File Reading method above).

Comment: Can you post the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two nested loops that each execute `anyLines.length` times. If there are four lines in the file, the inner loop will execute 16 times.

Comment: That's embarrassing :o, you're right! Thanks!

Comment: Now the only problem remains is replacing the characters with the binary.